# Selenium Webdriver - click on hidden elements with multiple element on same ID

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate upload file functionality in my project. The problem is two upload button was using the same ID and name.

None of the user actions would make this element visible. So I need a work around to click on the element while it is not visible.

Here's the images of html and my project pic :

[image: https]

My Code :

```
WebElement fileInput = driver.findElement(By.name("indexPicName"));
String js = "arguments[0].style.height='auto'; arguments[0].type='visible';";
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(js, fileInput);
fileInput.sendKeys("E:\\testUploadPromotion\\16.jpg");
```

I'm catch an Exception -

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException - Element is not
>   currently visible and so may not be interacted with.

I have tried using `JavascriptExecutor`. But unable to find the exact syntax.

Error on while uploading image :

[Error auto created textfield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfPfM.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to convert `hidden` box to visible `text` box, you should use `.setAttribute('type', 'text')` as below :-

```
WebElement fileInput = driver.findElement(By.id("indexPicName"));
String js = "arguments[0].setAttribute('type', 'text');return arguments[0]";
fileInput  = (WebElement)((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(js, fileInput);
fileInput.sendKeys("E:\\testUploadPromotion\\16.jpg");
```

Or if you want to `sendKeys` on `file` element try as below :-

```
WebElement fileInput = driver.findElement(By.id("indexPic"));
fileInput.sendKeys("E:\\testUploadPromotion\\16.jpg");
```

And if there are two `file` input elements with the same id and name and you want to upload file on second element try using `findElements` and use index to sendKeys as below :-

```
List<WebElement> fileInputs = driver.findElements(By.id("indexPic"));
    fileInputs.get(1).sendKeys("E:\\testUploadPromotion\\16.jpg");
```

Hope it helps..:)

Comment: Hi i trying to implement your code in . however it seems not working to upload an file and it auto created an textfield.

Comment: @thronewax it will just convert hidded text field to visible text field. I'm just giving you how to make it visible...What do you want actually..??

Comment: i want to upload the file not creating  the textfields . Sorry if i make you misunderstanding

Comment: @thronewax but you are trying to make visible hidden input box as your coded provided, anyway if you want to upload file try with updated answer..:)

Comment: Hi , its working with your updated answer . What if there is 2 upload button with same id? how to upload with the 2nd button? Kindly advice

Comment: @thronewax ok then use findElements and get all upload button and use index to sendKeys.. try updated answer...:)

Comment: I trying to use this code but seems not working inputs = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']"));
   inputs[1].sendKeys("path/to/first/file");
   inputs[2].sendKeys("path/to/first/file");

Comment: @thronewax why are using xpath while it could be simply find by I'd..I hae updated it try with second updated...

Comment: Use `inputs.get(0)` and `inputs.get(1)` instead...:)

Comment: Hi  sorry to trouble you again . I had change the code as you show me but i getting indexoufofboundexception : index 1 , size 1 ? what mean of this ? please help

Comment: @thronewax Oh it means there is only only one upload button with the id...may be second upload button I'd is different...try to print elements size it would be sure 1.  And you are passing index more than one thats why you are in trouble...:)

Comment: @thronewax check HTML for second file.. may be it would be different because you are getting only one element `By.id("indexPic")`...